# Find friendly url from term guid using javascript

Tags: 2013, jsom, term-store, managed-navigation

We have a cross-site publishing setup with a managed navigation from terms that the items are marked with. On the item pages I have the term or terms that a given item is marked with. I have both their names and their GUIDs, but I imagine the GUIDs will be more direct.

For example I have a document that is marked with both Mobile and Tools terms and I have the following GUIDs for this item:

```
GP0|#0c422db8-7973-44e5-b35a-c46cf1b7aa49;
L0|#00c422db8-7973-44e5-b35a-c46cf1b7aa49|Learning team tools and process;
GTSet|#0a31782c-ceb0-459f-b625-d98753c26922;
GPP|#8a7d2039-55e5-4b65-99bb-354bc53a9d1e;
GP0|#bf624af6-190a-4047-b3bf-238c8a60e8d7;
L0|#0bf624af6-190a-4047-b3bf-238c8a60e8d7|Mobile-accessible learning
```

The ones that start with GP0 are the ones I am interested in finding the friendly urls for.

I'm finding a few tutorials on how to work with the term store in C# like [this one](https://msftplayground.com/2013/01/retrieve-the-friendly-url-of-a-publishing-page/) but I need to do this client side with javascript and I'm not sure how to translate C# into the corresponding javascript api.

Does anyone know how to get the friendly url for a term given the guid? Thanks.

**Edit: Code to get the term**

I've found this code to retrieve the term from the GUID.

```
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15";

$.getScript(scriptbase +"/sp.runtime.js",function(){    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.publishing.js",function(){
            $.getScript(scriptbase+"/sp.taxonomy.js",function(){
                getTermByGuid('974f8fd6-99f5-49f2-a5ee-cdf536f5cfcb');
            })
        })
    })
})

function getTermByGuid(guid){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var tax = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
    var term = tax.getTerm(guid);
    ctx.load(tax);
    ctx.load(term); 
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log(term);  
    })  
}
```

The Term has all kinds of info in it, but nothing for the friendly url -- at least that I can find. I don't know if it is there and I just can't figure out how to get it or if I need to make a request to include it.

Also I've found some other examples that reference **SP.Publishing.Navigation.TaxonomyNavigation.getTermSetForWeb** but not in terms of jsom, only C#.

Comment: I did find this dotsa's answer in this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136047/sharepoint-2013-get-all-taxonomy-terms-jsom. It is a bit of overkill -- gets everything in the term group and (in my case)  has 124+ network calls and takes about 10+ seconds to run. Not so feasible for every page in my site. I can't see how to just extract the bit I need.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve navigation behavior and properties for a `SP.Taxonomy.Term` object the [`SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj994647.aspx) is intended, the following example demonstrates how to retrieve those properties by Term Id:

```
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15";

$.getScript(scriptbase +"/sp.runtime.js",function(){    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.publishing.js",function(){
            $.getScript(scriptbase+"/sp.taxonomy.js",function(){

                var termId = "--YOUR TERM GUID HERE--";


                var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);

                var term = taxSession.getTerm(termId);
                var navTerm = SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm.getAsResolvedByWeb(ctx,term, ctx.get_web(), "CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider");

                var displayUrl = navTerm.getResolvedDisplayUrl();
                var friendlyUrl = navTerm.getWebRelativeFriendlyUrl();

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                   console.log(friendlyUrl.get_value());
                   console.log(displayUrl.get_value());
                },
                function(sender,args) {
                   console.log(args.get_message());
                });
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it isn't working. Neither the friendly nor the display url are showing the customized shortcut. They both return slightly different versions of the default url. I found some documentation which maybe suggested get_friendlyUrlSegment or get_catalogTargetUrl, but I can't get those to load.